# JQuery Replace Span by Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html element:

```
<span id="4" style="display: block">
  <div>
    <span>ttttttt</span>
    <p>ttttttt</p>
  </div>
</span>
```

I want to change the outermost span to div, so it looks like:

```
<div id="4" style="display: block">
  <div>
    <span>ttttttt</span>
    <p>ttttttt</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I checked online and find a solution:

```
var myNodes = $('[type="type1"]')

myNodes[0].replaceWith(function() {
return '<div>'+$(this).html()+'</div>';
});
```

However, it does not work. Screenshot below:

[image]

Can I get some help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGMRi.png)

Comment: in order to use `.replaceWith()` your element must be wrapped in jQuery.

Comment: if we overlook the fact that an element's id should not start with a number then it would be `$("#4").replaceWith(`

Comment: Thanks! I used var myNodes = $('[type="type1"]') to select nodes.

Comment: why do you think that `$('[type="type1"]')` will select the span? But anyway, if you want to use the jQuery array `myNodes`, as said above, you need to wrap the element in jQuery, something like `$(myNodes[0]).replaceWith` or `myNodes.eq(0).replaceWith`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen numeric IDs are not forbidden in html5 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `JQuery` it will look like this:

```
var nestedSpan = $('#4 span:first');
var nestedSpanText = nestedSpan.text();
nestedSpan.replaceWith('<div>' + nestedSpanText + '</div>');
```

But imao it is very bad idea to name `id` page anchor as number.

Your solution also was not so bad. Just needed better selector:

```
var nestedSpan = $('#4 span:first');

nestedSpan.replaceWith(function() {
    return '<div>'+$(this).html()+'</div>';
});
```

Comment: When we change tag by this code we: 1. copy nested html 2. destroy old tag 3. create new tag on it place. 4. place inner html back. So if you want more operations with this element you need reselect it. I suggest you to set custom `id` for reselecting: `return '<div id="nested-span">'+$(this).html()+'</div>';` and select by it like : `$('#nested-span').outerHtml`

Answer (score 0):

Span may not contain a div (which I why you want to change it?

Also I would never use a numeric ID

Try this

```js
$("#Span4").replaceWith(function() {
  return $("<div/>", {
    "style": this.getAttribute("style"),
    "id": this.id
  }).html($(this).html());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="Span4" style="display: block">
  <div>
    <span>ttttttt</span>
    <p>ttttttt</p>
  </div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#4 div').unwrap().wrap('<div id="4" style="display: block;"></div>');
```

```js
$('#4 div').unwrap().wrap('<div id="4" style="display: block;"></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="4" style="display: block">
  <div>
    <span>ttttttt</span>
    <p>ttttttt</p>
  </div>
</span>
```